# is there any image processor with vim like keybinding?

Tags: vim

years ago, i see a report that there is an image processor just using vim like keybinding
i am a vim user and i like this style
so i want to use it
if there is,tell me the name or give me a link
if there is not,i want to make it myself,but could someone show me a simple demo by using vim keybinding

Comment: I anyone stumbles upon this, you can use `feh` with custom bindings, e.g. https://gist.github.com/yudi-matsuzake/688a6273339cbb2d7a97a53d0d8ab6c7

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, you can use AutoHotkey to remap the application's native key events to your own Vim-style bindings. For example, when I have Excel open, I can navigate around cells using my standard directional letter keys, by remapping them to behave like arrow keys; then when I need to edit a cell, I press `i`, as with Vim (`i` is remapped to `F2`).

You can remap complex key combinations to simpler ones for a Vim-like feel. For example, if your image processor of choice deletes something with `Ctrl+d` and Undo is `Ctrl+z`, you can remap this so that delete is just `x` or `d` or both, and remap undo to just `u`.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of. If you want a demo of keybinding that has been implemented in a non-vim environment, take a look at [vimperator](http://www.calmar.ws/firefox/) plugin for Firefox. It brings vim-like keybinding to Firefox.

Comment: I reccmoned [Pentadactyl](http://dactyl.sourceforge.net/pentadactyl/) over Vimperator.

Answer (score 0):

On what platform? For X there's feh or xzgv, for the Linux console there's fbi.

[This may help](http://textmode.at/2008/6/5/filemanager-and-imageviewer-with-vim-keybindings)

Answer (score 0):

vimperator is great

when in any text field, or the url bar, type C-t and your in "TEXTAREA" mode! which is like command mode in vi inside the textfield or textarea. awesome!

only thing to get used to is using C-t instead of escape (or C-[)

expect to hit the wrong one a few times

Comment: Last time I looked Vimperator was not an image processor.. And also, please recommend [Pentadactyl](http://dactyl.sourceforge.net/pentadactyl/) instead, it's a better fork of Vimperator

Comment: ? confused about your reference to it as an image processor, and your welcome to recommend Pentadactyl I'm very satisfied with vimperator for what I need

Comment: To quote the question "is there any image processor with vim like keybinding?"

Comment: my bad, found this thread by googling for vim keybindings for firefox